# Listing Products List when clicking the checkbox which comes from Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My question is about listing product list. I have a category list I've created with **checkbox**. 
When clicking the checkbox, the product list must be listed according checkbox.
I tried to do with json and ajax,but I didn't manage to do.
Are there are any ideas ?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKgVn.png)

Comment: AJAX is definitely the way to go. Call an action that receives the product category as parameter and renders a partial view with the product list. In the AJAX success handler, insert the resulting HTML into the DOM. Show what you have tried so far so we can give you more concrete help.

Comment: you create one ajax call which will send all the filters to your api, api will get the filters and get the data accordingly, and you get the result  and bind it to your view

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean passing values from the cheeckbox in the View to the controller?

You can use Ajax for this;
insert the checkboxes in a form element and set the `Id` attribute of the form
something like "FormId";

```
function Submit() {        
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/Index",
        type: "POST",
        data: $("#FormId").serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.Durum == "OK") {
                $('#FormId').html("Successful");
          }
```

And the html;

```
<form id="FormId">  

<input id="checkBox" type="checkbox" name="Data">
<button onclick="Submit()"> Submit</button>
</form>
```

In the controller;

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(var Data)
    {
      //your code here
      return Json("OK", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Notify the `name` attribute in the checkbox has the same value in the controller `Index` method's input parameter. You can pass variety of data regardless of data types, with serialize method of Ajax to the method in the controller, it will catch the right data as long as the `name` attribute and the input of the `Index` method have the same value.

If you want to pass only single data, just get the value of the certain form element with `.val` in the js code;

```
function Submit() {        
  $.ajax({
    url: "/Home/Index",
    type: "POST",
    data: $("checkBox").val(),
    success: function (result) {
        if (result == "OK") {
            $('#FormId').html("Successful");
      }
```

And also notify the `POST` type in the ajax function, this means you should put `[HttpPost]` attribute to the `Index` method in the controller. In the screenshots you shared, you call the ajax method with GET method but in the controller you receive it with the `[HttpPost]` attribute, this wont work.